# fourier transformation for heaviside function

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

i need to find the explicit formula for the following function 
$
H(\left | a \right |-x)
$
where $ H(.) $ be Heaviside function, x be variable and a is constant.

Comment: Please use latex to format equations. What is "mod"? The modulo operator? Do you want $a \mod x$? It currently looks like $a - \mod(x)$, so I cannot tell what you mean.

Comment: $ H(\left | a \right |-x) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier Transform of the Heaviside function is

$$
\mathcal{F}(H(x))=\hat{H}(\omega) = {1 \over 2}\delta(\omega) - {j \over 2\pi\omega}.
$$

The time reversal property of the Fourier transform states that $\mathcal{F}(f(-x)) = \hat{f} (-\omega)$.

The shifting property of the Fourier Transform states that $\mathcal{F}(f(x-a))=\hat{f}(\omega)e^{j\omega a}$.

If you combine the above three items, you can get the formula you are looking for.